# How to replace character 0x1f in a field in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database where for whatever reason a field contains the character 0x1f. I wish to delete this character from each row in the table that contains 0x1f.

The closest I can find to even finding the affected rows (that works) is "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE FIELDNAME <> CONVERT( FIELDNAME USING ASCII )", but am having no joy at this, either in phpmyadmin of using php.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Appologies for the confusion. the 0x1f is not in the field name, it's in the field row/s.

EDIT2:
As a sidenote, on the site itself I used "$title = preg_replace( '/[^[:print:]\r\n]/', '',$title);" for a data export to remove the unwanted character, but have been requested to clean up the database itself.

EDIT3:

What is working so far, using copy and paste from notepad++, but instead of the %% I see %FS%. I copied the FS from the export using notpad++. (Hope that makes sense)

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$sql="select post_title from wp_posts where post_title like '%%'";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    //print_r($row);
    echo $row['post_title']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: would something like `UPDATE TABLENAME SET FIELDNAME=REPLACE(FIELDNAME,CHAR(31),'')` work? Or even `UPDATE TABLENAME SET FIELDNAME=SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDNAME,CHAR(31),1)`

Comment: Alas no. I did try this from another answer, but it's not the fieldname with the problem.

Comment: what? that won't replace that character from the "fieldname" but the data inside that column. I'm not suggesting altering the table column name. That is just an update that will replace all of the `0x1f` from the rows of data.

Comment: Aha. Sorry for the misunderstanding, but as I stated it didn't work. I just get "0 rows affected" for both answers.

Comment: that should affect all rows, even if nothing is changed, as there is no where clause. Are you sure the table has rows?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. 567 rows in fact. I just tried it again and get  "0 rows affected"???

Comment: If you can replace the character in php, they why not just use php to query the data, replace and update the data without the hex character. Even if there were millions of rows, it would only take a few minutes for php to power through it. under 600 rows and likely take about 3 seconds to run.

Comment: Lol. Yes, that is what I am busy working on..... not as clean as I would have liked, but I am sure it will work. Still, it relies on using copy and paste for the character, so I would think there must be a more 'correct' way to do this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if you go into phpmyadmin and export the table data to an SQL file, you could open that in textpad and just find/replace the character then re-import the data. Might be quicker. This is one of those things where finding the "clean" or slick way doesn't really matter. Quickly doing brute force and "git'er done" can be completed in the time it would take to research the slick way. Then just prevent those characters going in the database in the future and problem solved.

Comment: Agreed Jonathan. The export/import route was just as simple. However, I would think there should be a mysql query way to do this..... but plus 1 for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herewith the final script that worked, based on the other answers and comments. Keep in mind "%%" is actually %FS%" where FS is copied form an export viewed using notepad++, as the character encoding in this textbox hides the character 0x1f.

I would still like to know if this is possible in mysql without using php, so will at this point leave the question as unanswered. Thanks to everyone for the help.

```
function connect($host, $user, $pass, $db)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    if($mysqli->connect_error) 
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
    return $mysqli; 
}
$mysqli=connect("localhost","user","password","dbname");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$sql="select id,post_title from wp_posts where post_title like '%%'";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $title = preg_replace( '/[^[:print:]\r\n]/', '',$row['post_title']);
    $newsql="update wge8b198b_posts set post_title=\"".$title."\" where id=".$row['id'];
    $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($newsql);
    $stmt2->execute();
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually in MySQL when you inserted **0x1f** value then it will be stored as **31** if that column is **INT data type**. The below query would be useful.

> select * from TABLENAME WHERE FIELDNAME = 31

If the column is **VARCHAR** or **CHAR** data type then **0x1f** value will be inserted. The below query would be useful.

> select * from TABLENAME WHERE FIELDNAME = '0x1f'

If a character contains the **'0x1f'** in it, You can use

> select * from TABLENAME where FIELDNAME like '%0x1f%';

Comment: No. it's a varchar, and I suspect the invalid char came from an import or a hack.

Comment: I think it was inserted as it is like (0x1f). So you can use select * from TABLENAME WHERE FIELDNAME = '0x1f'

Comment: No it didn;t work, as the character is within the field, so it would need a like statement I would think.

Comment: if you have database access check the column value in database and make the select according to that

Comment: you can use  select * from TABLENAME where FIELDNAME like '%0x1f%';

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myCol = REPLACE(myCol, '%1f', UNHEX('1f'))
WHERE myCol LIKE '%\%1f%';
```

Comment: Alas no as well. My problem lies in the field rows, not the field name

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. In a wordpress table I have a number of rows containing the 0x1f character. I am battling to even search for those rows, and " LIKE '%\%1f%'" returned a null set.

Comment: This is hard to test without data. Can you provide a `INSERT` statement? If not: Look for the MySQL Hex-handling functions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

Comment: Doing an export the relevant field show as, for example,  "data[FS] more data", where [FS] is the symbol for 0x1f. Other than that I cannot post the insert statement, as is does not show the FS correctly in these text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the unwanted character "0x1F" from the table "wp_posts" column "post_title".

```
UPDATE [wp_posts]
SET [post_title] = REPLACE([post_title], CHAR(0x1F), '')
WHERE [post_title] LIKE'%' + CHAR(0x1F) + '%'
```